# Show that every bounded above sequence $x_{n}$ tends to $-\infty$ or there exists $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck on how to show that either $\limsup$ does exist or the sequence tends to  $-\infty$ when the sequence is bounded above. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose that the sequence does not tend to $-\infty$.  If we negate the definition of convergence to $-\infty$, we find that this means:

> There exists an $L \in \Bbb R$ such that there are *infinitely many* $n$ for which $x_n \geq L$.

Of course, the sequence has an upper bound, which is to say that there is a $U \in \Bbb R$ such that $x_n \leq U$ for every $n$.  Using these two statements, you should now show that the lim sup exists.

As a further hint: start by convincing yourself that the limsup (if it exists) must fall between $L$ and $U$.